# DataReader.loadAsync is being completed even when unconsumedBufferLength is 0

Tags: javascript, typescript, windows-runtime

I'm consuming JSON stream on UWP WinRT with this code:

```
async function connect() {
    let stream: MSStream;
    return new CancellableContext<void>(
        async (context) => {
            // this will be called immediately
            stream = await context.queue(() => getStreamByXHR()); // returns ms-stream object
            await consumeStream(stream);
        },
        {
            revert: () => {
                // this will be called when user cancels the task
                stream.msClose();
            }
        }
    ).feed();
}

async function consumeStream(stream: MSStream) {
    return new CancellableContext<void>(async (context) => {
        const input = stream.msDetachStream() as Windows.Storage.Streams.IInputStream;
        const reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(input);
        reader.inputStreamOptions = Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.partial;

        while (!context.canceled) {
            const content = await consumeString(1000);
            // ... some more codes
        }

        async function consumeString(count: number) {
            await reader.loadAsync(count); // will throw when the stream gets closed
            return reader.readString(reader.unconsumedBufferLength);
        }
    }).feed();
}
```

Here, the document about [`InputStreamOptions.partial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.storage.streams.inputstreamoptions.aspx) says:

> The asynchronous read operation completes when one or more bytes is available.

However, `reader.loadAsync` completes even when `reader.unconsumedBufferLength` is 0 and this makes CPU load. Is this an API bug or can I prevent this behavior so that `loadAsync` can complete only when `unconsumedBufferLength` is greater than 0?

**PS:** Here is a repro with pure JS: https://github.com/SaschaNaz/InputStreamOptionsBugRepro

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an API bug or can I prevent this behavior so that loadAsync can complete only when unconsumedBufferLength is greater than 0

Most likey it also completes at the *end of stream*. So in that case the `unconsumedBufferLength` will be zero and needs to be catered for.

In fact the example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.aspx shows something similar (admittedly not using that option):

```
            // Once we have written the contents successfully we load the stream.
            await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);

            var receivedStrings = "";

            // Keep reading until we consume the complete stream.
            while (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
```

Comment: Ah, the `canceled` variable here will be true when the stream gets disconnected so `loadAsync` won't be called in that case.

Comment: @KagamiSaschaRosylight show the logic for the canceled variable

Comment: Okay, I added more lines. `loadAsync` will just throw an error with a disconnected stream, anyway: `WinRTError: The object has been closed.` I can confirm that `loadAsync` is never being called after disconnection.